# margin работает неожиданным образом

Tags: html, css

При прописании margin-top для header в ожидании отступа от верхней части блока-родителя, ничего не происходит, что в данном случае лучше всего предпринять?

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

.main {
    width: 350px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: rgb(28, 126, 126);
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

header {
    height: 80px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: aqua;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <header></header>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Вы ведь знаете что можно выбрать все элементы через `*` да? А та которые не угоды просто отфильтровать через `:not` (Пример: `*:not(script, style, p)`)? Ведь да?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, не неожиданным образом, это предсказуемое поведение margin – [схлопывание внешних отступов](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing).

Или добавляйте `padding` в пиксель для родительского блока, или в принципе не пытайтесь отступы от родительского блока делать через `margin` у первого дочернего, а воспользуйтесь `padding` у родительского.

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

.main {
    width: 350px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: rgb(28, 126, 126);
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    padding: 1px;
}

header {
    border: 5px solid #000;
    height: 80px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: aqua;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <header></header>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```